# regex to match any number which is greater than 5

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need to match fail counts greater than 5.

```
string="""fail_count 7

fail_count 8

fail_count 9

fail count 7

fail_count 71

fail_count 23
"""

match = re.search(r'fail(\s|\_)count\s[5-9]', string)

if match:

    print match.group()
```

I am able to match up to 9, but if I increase the range to 999 it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean greater than (>) or *at least* 5 (>=)? The regex would suggest that it's the latter.

Comment: Does this need to be a pure-regex answer? (If so, why?) Could you not just match **any digits**, then cast the string into an integer and use a normal `> 5` check?

Comment: `re.search` will return the 1st occurrence. If you need all occurrences - it won't help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

5-9 or at least 2 digits

```
'([5-9]|\d{2,})'
```

or to match the whole numbre when it starts by 5-9.

5-9 followed by any number of digits or at least 2 digits

```
'([5-9]\d*|\d{2,})'
```

Comment: Small issue with your regex there. It would have validated 04. `([5-9]|[1-9]\d+)`

Comment: @MikeAlmond, because used without context, it's not anchored on the left but only the relevant part, anchored: `^([5-9]\d*|\d{2,})` or could be from the posted question `...count\s([5-9]\d*|\d{2,})`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this regex solution can help

`fail(\s|\_)count\s([0-9]{2,}|[5-9]{1})`

see on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PPKcnc/2/)